# Call an action from JS file instead of the view (MVC 4)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the MVC 4.

In my view i can simply get an action's url by using the: @Url.Action

Now i wanted to make a javascript file with all the view's javascript instead of writing it all in the view, the problem is i can't use the razor's stuff anymore.

so my question is how can i get the action's url from a javascript separated file?

Comment: What kind of things are you using Razor for in Javascript?

Comment: for example when I make an ajax call, I use the @Url.Action("x","y"), to get the url for.

Comment: Why don't you use HTML5 `data-*` attributes to store stuff? For example, when I am iterating over a list of items and presenting them in a table (very simple), but I want to add buttons for "Edit" and "Delete" for each row, I don't want hardcode the `id` (or several other pieces of information) of the Database row in multiple places. So, I just put it on the table's row, like: `<tr data-my-row-id="<%= Row.id %>">...</tr>` and it's pretty easy to get with Javascript, much easier with jQuery

Comment: yeah that's also a solution, very similar to storing the url in a js variable...it's that i just don't want to make the code dirty, just thought there must be a "nicer" solution for that...i'll think about using that if I won't find anything else...thanks!

Comment: Well, I _guess_ it's "similar". It doesn't pollute the global Javascript scope, available everywhere, and is what the `data-*` attribute is made for - metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define a JavaScript variable within your view that you can then use in your script.  Obviously this must be declared first.

I use a helper on my layout pages that has all these variables and a section for any I'd want specific to a page.  Note these would come before any other script references before the body tag.

```
@Scripts.Variables()
@RenderSection("ScriptVariables", false)
```

The `Scripts.Variables` is something like this

```
@helper Variables()
{
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var ActionGetallAdmin = '@Url.Action("GetAll", "Admin")';
        var ActionAccountLogin = '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")';
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but seems like it's overkill to "save" all the used actions' url. that's will be my very last solution. thanks for that!

Comment: don't see how else you'll get the url within a js file.

Comment: This is the cleanest implementation of this that I have seen to date, thanks for providing it.  I agree this is the best method as it keeps things contained logically and will still respect changes to your underlying routes.

Answer (score 0):

One way I did this before was to create views that served JS files (and CSS files, actually), instead of HTML files. This leverages the fact that views aren't necessarily HTML files all the time in the MVC paradigm.

You could do this by creating a controller for it:

```
public class AssetController : Controller {

    protected void SetMIME(string mimeType) {

        // implementation largely removed
        this.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = mimeType;
        this.Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    }

    // this will render a view as a Javascript file
    public void ActionResult MyJavascript() {

        this.SetMIME("text/javascript");
        return View();
    }

}
```

Once you've done that, you can create a view (using the way you normally do it in ASP.NET MVC), and just write it up as Javascript. Remember not to use a layout, as you obviously don't want that.

Everything that views in MVC has to offer is available to you, so feel free to use models, et al.

```
@model IList<Entity>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

(function ($) {

    // javascript!

    @foreach(var entity in Model) {
        $('#@entity.Id').on('click', function () {
            console.log('@entity.Name');
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Then you can wire that up using old-fashioned Razor in your other views.

```
<script src="@Url.Action("MyJavascript","Asset")"></script>
```

Which will roll out something like

```
<script src="http://your.domain/asset/myjavascript"></script>
```

Works like a charm. The views are dynamically created, of course, so be wary if you're nit-picky about that. However, since they *are* MVC controller actions and views, you can set cache options on them just as with any other view.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... I think you can define a special route, like "actionsjs", that points to an action.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "actionsJs",
                url: "actionsjs",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetActions" });
```

In the action you've to set the content to the right type:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
```

Then you'll return a specific View that will contains javascript code with some Razor inside.

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}

$(function() {
    var a = @(1 + 2);
});
```

At this point you'll able to add this "script file" to your site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="@Url.Action("GetActions", "Home")"></script>
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the root path, use a variable on layout and use that in JavaScript file, say

```
// In layout view
<script>
  var rootPath = @Url.Content("~/")
</script>
```

User `rootPath` anywhere in your application JavaScript files

If you want to get full path of a controller with action then

```
// View
<script>
  var url = @Url.Content("ActionName", "ControllerName")
</script>
```

use url in your JavaScript file.